# How to avoid screen corruption?

Tags: redraw

I'd been using Linux Mint MATE for years, and recently moved to Arch Linux with MATE Desktop Environment without any change of hardware or `.vimrc`. (By the way, I use no plugin.) After that, when I open a file on vim and

- scroll up/down
- or, minimize the window and un-minimize it later
- or, use "show deskop" functionality and then unuse it

, the screen is sometimes be corrupted in a way that the same lines are apparently duplicated. This has never occurred on Linux Mint on the same machine, and Linux Mint on MacbookPro.

For example, the first picture is a healthy state without any corruption.

[image]

The opened file consists only of ASCII characters (with UTF-8 encodings) and short enough not to cause memory problems. This screen can sometimes be (corruptions are underlined):

[image]

[image]

Pressing Ctrl+L to redraw the display solves the problem, but it is really annoying.

What is bad is that I don't know when it occurs. So I cannot reproduce the problem to debug or find the cause.

What I tried is

- uninstall Arch's original `vim` and compile `vim` from the official source, because I did so also on Linux Mint
- do some gpu settings
- unset `TERM`, `COLORTERM` or try many values of them according to [scrolling is messed up](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/6802) and [Vim NerdTree corrupts when using Tmux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45245919/vim-nerdtree-corrupts-when-using-tmux) (NOTE: I do not use `tmux` or `screen`.)
- change HDMI-cable to a quality one
- change startup command bound to `mate-terminal` from the default `bash` to `env TERM=xterm bash`
- unset `cursorline`
- change terminal emulator from `mate-terminal` to `gnome-terminal`
- `:set term=`*builtin_term* (see `help builtin-terms`)
- `:set nottybuiltin` (this made the frequency of occurrence larger)
- reinstall everything including the OS (<s>It seems the problem has been solved. But I'm still checking whether it really has.</s> Still occurs.)
- unset `cursorline` <s>(This worked like a charm. Now it seems the problem quite very rarely (but still) occurs. After a week or so, I'll append if the problem has really been solved or not.) (As [@Rich](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21461/how-to-avoid-screen-corruption#comment41460_21461) pointed out, I had already tried this before. At that time, unsetting the options didn't work well. Perhaps this difference comes from the difference of versions...)</s> No. Still occurs.
- refine compile options (see below) -> It seems the problem is solved. I haven't observed it for more than two months.

What I don't want to do is

- change font
- change desktop environment

Does anyone have an idea why that occurs? I really want to solve the problem.

---

Environment:

I'll add any information if required.

```sh
#This is the information at the time I posted this question.
#Please scroll down to see the lastest information.

~ $ neofetch
OS: Arch Linux x86_64
Kernel: Linux 5.3.5-arch1-1-ARCH
Shell: bash 5.0.11
Resolution: 1920x1080 @ 60.00Hz
Terminal: mate-terminal
CPU: Intel i5-7500 (4) @ 3.8GHz [39.0°C]
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
Memory: 1405MiB / 15978MiB [=--------------]
CPU Usage: 2% [---------------]
Locale: en_US.UTF-8 

~ $ vi --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Oct  4 2019 02:04:19)
Included patches: 1-2109
Compiled by me
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_any_white
+arabic            +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tcl
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       +termguicolors
+autochdir         +float             +multi_byte        +terminal
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_lang        +terminfo
+balloon_eval      -footer            -mzscheme          +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +textobjects
+browse            +gettext           +num64             +textprop
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +packages          +timers
+byte_offset       +iconv             +path_extra        +title
+channel           +insert_expand     -perl              +toolbar
+cindent           +job               +persistent_undo   +user_commands
+clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
+clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +virtualedit
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           +python/dyn        +visual
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3/dyn       +visualextra
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +viminfo
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +vreplace
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cscope            +localmap          -ruby              +wildmenu
+cursorbind        -lua               +scrollbind        +windows
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +writebackup
+dialog_con_gui    +mksession         +smartindent       +X11
+diff              +modify_fname      +sound             -xfontset
+digraphs          +mouse             +spell             +xim
+dnd               +mouseshape        +startuptime       +xpm
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +statusline        +xsmp_interact
+emacs_tags        +mouse_gpm         -sun_workshop      +xterm_clipboard
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +tag_binary        
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         -tag_old_static    
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.
0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/lib/libffi
-3.2.1/include -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/li
bpng16 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libmoun
t -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -pthread    -g -O2 -D_REENTRANT  -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORT
IFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -l
atk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lharfbuz
z -lfontconfig -lfreetype  -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo -lelf -lnsl    -l
canberra  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl           

#Here is the lastest information.

~ $ neofetch
OS: Arch Linux x86_64 
Kernel: Linux 5.5.2-arch1-1 
Shell: bash 5.0.11 
Resolution: 1920x1080 @ 60.00Hz 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: Intel i5-7500 (4) @ 3.8GHz [25.0°C] 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti 
Memory: 2175MiB / 15978MiB [==-------------] 
CPU Usage: 9% [=--------------] 
Locale: en_US.UTF-8 

~ $ vi --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Feb  9 2020 11:55:29)
Included patches: 1-235
Compiled by me
#(Contents below are exactly same as the above ones except `+popupwin` (this functionality was added in version 8.2).)
```

By the way, I'm not experiencing the problem other than on `vim` (until today). `less` and any GUI applications like `firefox` work well.

---

Additional information:

This is the value of `TERM`.

```
~ $ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

This is the output of `:pu =execute('set termcap')`.

```
--- Terminal codes ---
  t_AL=^[[%p1%dL      t_DL=^[[%p1%dM      t_mr=^[[7m          t_se=^[[27m         t_u7=^[[6n
  t_al=^[[L           t_dl=^[[M           t_ms=y              t_Sf=               t_ue=^[[m
  t_bc=               t_EC=^G             t_nd=^[[C           t_SH=^[[%p1%d q     t_us=^[[4m
  t_BE=^[[?2004h      t_EI=               t_op=^[[39;49m      t_SI=               t_ut=y
  t_BD=^[[?2004l      t_fs=^G             t_RF=^[]10;?^G      t_Si=^[[22;1t       t_vb=
  t_cd=^[[J           t_GP=^[[13t         t_RB=^[]11;?^G      t_so=^[[7m          t_ve=^[[?25h
  t_ce=^[[K           t_IE=^G             t_RC=^[[?12$p       t_SR=               t_vi=^[[?25l
  t_cl=^[[H^[[2J      t_IS=^[]1;          t_RI=^[[%p1%dC      t_sr=^[M            t_VS=^[[?12l
  t_Ce=               t_ke=^[[?1l^[>      t_Ri=^[[23;1t       t_ST=^[[22;2t       t_vs=^[[?12h
  t_Co=256            t_ks=^[[?1h^[=      t_RS=^[P$q q^[\     t_Te=^[[29m         t_xn=y
  t_CS=               t_le=^H             t_RT=^[[23;2t       t_TE=^[[>4;m        t_xs=
  t_CV=               t_mb=^[[5m          t_RV=^[[>c          t_TI=^[[>4;2m       t_ZH=^[[3m
  t_da=               t_md=^[[1m          t_Sb=               t_Ts=^[[9m          t_ZR=^[[23m
  t_db=               t_me=^[[m           t_SC=^[]12;         t_ts=^[]2;
  t_AB=^[[%?%p1%{8}%<%t4%p1%d%e%p1%{16}%<%t10%p1%{8}%-%d%e48;5;%p1%d%;m
  t_AF=^[[%?%p1%{8}%<%t3%p1%d%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;%p1%d%;m
  t_cm=^[[%i%p1%d;%p2%dH
  t_Cs=^[]12;%p1%s^G
  t_cs=^[[%i%p1%d;%p2%dr
  t_te=^[[?1049l^[[23;0;0t
  t_ti=^[[?1049h^[[22;0;0t
  t_WP=^[[3;%p1%d;%p2%dt
  t_WS=^[[8;%p1%d;%p2%dt
  t_8f=^[[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum
  t_8b=^[[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum
--- Terminal keys ---
t_#2 <S-Home>    ^[[1;2H   t_KH <k5>        ^[O*u     t_kb <BS>        ^?
t_#4 <S-Left>    ^[[1;2D   t_KI <k6>        ^[O*v     t_kd <Down>      ^[O*B
t_%1 <Help>      ^[[28;*~  t_KJ <k7>        ^[O*w     t_kh <Home>      ^[[1;*H
t_%i <S-Right>   ^[[1;2C   t_KK <k8>        ^[O*x     t_kl <Left>      ^[O*D
t_&8 <Undo>      ^[[26;*~  t_KL <k9>        ^[O*y     t_kr <Right>     ^[O*C
t_*7 <S-End>     ^[[1;2F   t_PE <PasteEnd>  ^[[201~   t_ku <Up>        ^[O*A
t_@7 <End>       ^[[1;*F   t_PS <PasteStart> ^[[200~       <SgrMouse>  ^[[<*M
t_F1 <F11>       ^[[23;*~  t_k1 <F1>        ^[[11;*~       <Mouse>     ^[[M
t_F2 <F12>       ^[[24;*~  t_k2 <F2>        ^[[12;*~       <xF1>       ^[O*P
t_K1 <kHome>     ^[[1;*~   t_k3 <F3>        ^[[13;*~       <xF2>       ^[O*Q
t_K4 <kEnd>      ^[[4;*~   t_k4 <F4>        ^[[14;*~       <xF3>       ^[O*R
t_K6 <kPlus>     ^[O*k     t_k5 <F5>        ^[[15;*~       <xF4>       ^[O*S
t_K7 <kMinus>    ^[O*m     t_k6 <F6>        ^[[17;*~       <xEnd>      ^[O*F
t_K8 <kDivide>   ^[O*o     t_k7 <F7>        ^[[18;*~       <zEnd>      ^[[8;*~
t_K9 <kMultiply> ^[O*j     t_k8 <F8>        ^[[19;*~       <xHome>     ^[O*H
t_KA <kEnter>    ^[O*M     t_k9 <F9>        ^[[20;*~       <zHome>     ^[[7;*~
t_KB <kPoint>    ^[O*n     t_k; <F10>       ^[[21;*~       <xUp>       ^[[1;*A
t_KC <k0>        ^[O*p     t_kB <S-Tab>     ^[[Z           <xDown>     ^[[1;*B
t_KD <k1>        ^[O*q     t_kD <Del>       ^[[3~          <xLeft>     ^[[1;*D
t_KE <k2>        ^[O*r     t_kI <Insert>    ^[[2;*~        <xRight>    ^[[1;*C
t_KF <k3>        ^[O*s     t_kN <PageDown>  ^[[6;*~        <kDel>      ^[[3;*~
t_KG <k4>        ^[O*t     t_kP <PageUp>    ^[[5;*~
     <SgrMouseRelelase> ^[[<*m
```

This is the command I use to compile vim.

```
~ $ sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-compiledby=me --with-features=huge --with-x --enable-pythoninterp=dynamic --enable-python3interp=dynamic && sudo make install
```

<s>`--with-x` is needed since clipboard support is a must.</s> (I just noticed `--with-features=huge` implies `--with-x`.) `--enable-pythoninterp=dynamic` is not needed, so I'll omit this from now on. `--enable-python3interp=dynamic` is needed since I have some (not async) functions written in Python3 in `.vimrc` (they are all written by me and not external plugins).

Here's my `.vimrc` (with irrelevant or sensitive codes cut).

```
set t_Co=256
syntax on
set title
set mouse=
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set whichwrap=b,s,h,l,<,>,[,]
set virtualedit=onemore
set number
set display=lastline
set showcmd
set vb t_vb=
set hlsearch
set showmatch
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set autoindent
" set cursorline
set history=1000
set winheight=100
set cmdwinheight=10
set equalprg=sort
set conceallevel=2
set concealcursor=nvi
set tags=./tags
set diffopt+=vertical
set nrformats=
set timeoutlen=300
```

Comment: Even if you don't want to do it, it would be pretty helpful to test another terminal emulator. This would allow you to know if the problem comes from your terminal or from Vim itself (which seems unlikely). Also if you use tmux, you could try to reproduce the problem without tmux, maybe it is the culprit.

Comment: @statox I think you are totally right. Now I try `gnome-terminal` which is the base of `mate-terminal` and still active. (`mate-terminal` is not abandoned but the last update was 2 years ago.) After the try, I'll append the result to the post. This may takes time because I cannot intentionally reproduce the problem. By the way, I've never used `tmux` or `screen`. Anyway, thank you for your advice.

Comment: Do you have `lazyredraw` set? Maybe that's the cause.

Comment: @lisowski.r No. `nolazyredraw` is set. By the way, I don't use any plugins.

Comment: @ynn Even with `gnome-terminal`, the problem occurs.

Comment: try some of the builtin terminal descriptions, e.g. `:set term=builtin_ansi` (see `:set term=xxx` for possible values).

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thank you. I'll try it. (For my note: `help builtin-terms`, `help 'ttybuiltin'`)

Comment: This doesn't look like graphical glitch, but rather terminal glitch. It happens when multiple unsynchronised threads tried updating the terminal simultaneously. Try removing all your vim plugins and run basic vim with minimal config and put the plugins back one by one, there's likely multiple plugins that race each other when printing something to the screen, or probably you have a bg-ed (background) command running on the shell printing stuff while vim is running.

Comment: have you tried a different terminal?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt As written in the OP, I switched from `mate-terminal` to `gnome-terminal`. (I could do so because they are really similar in terms of interface and appearance. It seems a quite difficult to switch to a very different kind of terminal emulator (e.g. `tilix`, `konsole` etc) because that will force me to endure low productivity for a week or so. I will more annoyed by it more then by the current screen corruption.)

Comment: I would rather test with a terminal that has full `xterm` compatibility, just like well, xterm

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to ask this in a Linux forum?

Comment: @eyalkarni Um..., I'll consider seriously asking in a Linux forum. It is a good idea since I didn't observe the problem at all before switching OS from Linux Mint to Arch Linux.

Comment: You didn't by any chance start the program whose source you are editing in the background, did you?

Comment: @JürgenKrämer No. I only use vim to edit text files and the problem occurs for all text files (not specific to certain special files).

Comment: This is super weird. The fact that it only affects Vim, and occurs in different terminal emulators suggests it's a Vim issue, but the fact that you can reproduce it merely by displaying your desktop or minimising the terminal (Which I would have thought Vim would be completely unaware of: does the terminal call Vim to redraw itself when restoring the window? I would've guessed it would just redisplay the existing terminal contents?) suggests it's actually a terminal emulator issue.

Comment: Your latest edit states that unsetting `cursorline` has helped the issue, but `unset cursorline` was already in your list of things you've tried (you added it in Oct).

Comment: @Rich Ah, you are right. Really strange. But it's true that the problem occurred only once in this three days after I unset `cursorline`. Since I regularly compile the latest build (once a week or so), perhaps this difference comes from the difference of versions. Anyway, I have to continue to see if the problem has really been solved. (Yes, because the corruption still occurs, unsetting the option isn't the fundamental solution...)

Comment: No. Still occurs...

Comment: It really *really* REALLY looks like what's happening is your C++ program is running in background and it's running in the terminal. You're getting the exact strings it prints and the fact it's only jumping to the next line (and not flushing to the start of the line) is consistent with a program (such as Vim) setting terminal options for full screen... Are really really sure positive that your program is not running in background? Perhaps you have a Vim plugin that is compiling it and running it in background for some reason...

Comment: You should try `vim --clean` or `vim -u NONE -N` or similar to ensure it's not caused by any of your vimrc settings or your plugins is interfering with anything... Also, check `ps` output to make sure the binary is not running under you...

Comment: @filbranden Thank you. 1: The problem occurs for all sorts of documents (i.e. `.txt`, `.md`, `.cpp` and so on). Not only for source codes which can be executed. 2: As written in OP, I use no plugin at all. 3: As you recommend, I'll scan carefully `.vimrc` and execute `vim --clean` or its variants.

Comment: @ynn It's just really odd that the strings match what that program does exactly... Is it maybe something that's being launched by your bashrc or similar? With other types of text, do you still see the same messages ("sleep ends" and "sleep starts"?)

Comment: @filbranden I'm sorry the examples in OP are confusive. The match is the very coincidence. Even `#include <iostream>` or `int main() {` can be duplicated. Yes, any text.

Comment: @ynn Can you post some new screenshots then? I mean, those you have can be explained *so simply* by that process running in background... It would be nice to see some other cases you can't explain to see what is odd about those too...

Comment: @filbranden Of course. But it'll take some time (I can't tell how long) because I cannot intentionally reproduce the corruption. I'd be glad if you could wait patiently :) I'll once again reply to you when I add an additional screenshot.

Comment: @ynn Too long for a comment; too unreliable for an answer: https://0x0.st/ioyJ.txt

Comment: @user938271 Thank you. Could you make it an answer? I've read the document and thought there is much useful information. (Many future readers would hesitate to visit an unknown link.) By the way, I just added some information in response to your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I can reliably reproduce by yanking a couple lines then pasting once or twice. Screen does update.

Turning off line numbers in .vimrc fixed for me. But I wish I had more details.

Comment: The guidelines of the site us to focus on the factual part of the answer. You should probably focus first on the solution part. The comment part should be kept for the comment I understand you have to right to left yet :-/

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Posts like "I'm having this problem, too" aren't answers and shouldn't be posted as such, so I've edited those details out.